# Pagination is not working as expected with vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am pushing query parameter for page change it works fine:

```
getProducts(){

   this.$router
        .push({
          name: 'products',
          query: {
            page: this.page,
          },
        })
        .catch(() => {})
... fetching data from backend
}
```

It works fine when I just click pagination items and data is loading correctly but when I click back from browser query param is geting changed but pagination and data doesn't can't changed because this.page value remains the same. How can be this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a `befoureRouteUpdate(to, from, next)` hook in your component - or a watcher on `$route`. Vue-Router reuses the same component because you are not changing the route - only the query parameters.

Keep in mind that:

1. the `beforeRouteUpdate` will be called only when the component is being **reused** - not when the route is visited for the first time (for the latter you need `beforeRouteEnter`)
2. the watcher will be also called when you leave the route (e.g. if you go to `clients` page)